# Error on creating a new project in VS Community 2015 or building an old valid one

Tags: constructor

I have a problem that  stops me to create new project in VS Community 2015 and even don't let me build or debug any previous valid projects.

When I try to create new project (File->New->Project) I get a MessageBox with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

When I try to build an old valid project i receive the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()   CopyTool            
Error       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.GetBasePipeName(String compilerExeDirectory)   CopyTool            
Error       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)    CopyTool            
Error       at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create() CopyTool            
Error       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)   CopyTool            
Error       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)    CopyTool            
Error       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  CopyTool            
Error       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.GetPipeNameForPath(String compilerExeDirectory)    CopyTool            
Error       Unexpected exception:   CopyTool            
Error       System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.  CopyTool            
Error       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args) CopyTool            
Error       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.RunServerCompilation(RequestLanguage language, List`1 arguments, BuildPaths buildPaths, String keepAlive, String libEnvVariable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  CopyTool"
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks! 
Aurelian

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling FIPS Mode. Here are the steps:

1. Press Windows Key+R to open the Run dialog.
2. Type “gpedit.msc” into the Run dialog box (without the quotes) and press Enter.
3. Navigate to “Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local  Policies\Security Options” in the Group Policy Editor.
4. Locate the “System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing” setting in the right pane and double-click it.
5. Set the setting to “Disabled” and click “OK.”
6. Restart the computer.

Source:http://www.howtogeek.com/245859/why-you-shouldnt-enable-fips-compliant-encryption-on-windows/